# SSH host key pair expects passphrase causing ProFTPD to fail

Tags: docker, ssh-keys, proftpd

I need to create a docker image with ProFTPD and use it as SFTP server.
Obviously I need SSH host keys for this to work but I don't want to create new keys every time I build the image.
If I create SSH host keys with:

```
ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -t rsa
ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key -N '' -t dsa
```

inside a running container without providing passphrase works perfectly.
I can simply start my SFTP server with `proftpd` command.

However keys generated exactly the same way on my host and then copied to the docker image with `COPY` directive in `Dockerfile` cause the following error when trying to start ProFTPD in a container:

```
Wrong passphrase for this key.  Please try again.

Wrong passphrase for this key.  Please try again.

Wrong passphrase for this key.  Please try again.
2018-11-13 11:48:21,196 2771999b0891 proftpd[53924] 2771999b0891: mod_sftp/1.0.0: error reading passphrase for SFTPHostKey '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key': (unknown)
2018-11-13 11:48:21,197 2771999b0891 proftpd[53924] 2771999b0891: mod_sftp/1.0.0: unable to use key in SFTPHostKey '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key', exiting
```

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:** Dockerfile as requested:

```
FROM alpine:latest

COPY etc/apk/repositories /etc/apk/repositories

COPY etc/ssh/ /etc/ssh/

COPY etc/proftpd/ /etc/proftpd/

RUN apk upgrade --no-cache

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    proftpd \
    proftpd-mod_sql_postgres \
    proftpd-mod_sftp_sql

ENTRYPOINT proftpd
```

And the contents of `/etc/ssh` inside the container:

```
>>ls -la /etc/ssh
total 28
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Nov 13 13:47 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Nov 13 13:46 ..
-rw-------    1 root     root          1393 Nov 13 13:57 ssh_host_dsa_key
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           609 Nov 13 10:11 ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
-rw-------    1 root     root          1831 Nov 13 13:57 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           401 Nov 13 10:11 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3177 Nov  7 18:21 sshd_config
```

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of your Dockerfile.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've added it now

Comment: Huh? I don't see anything in that Dockerfile that creates ssh host keys. How did you actually create them, then?

Comment: @MichaelHampton `ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -t rsa` and `ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key -N '' -t dsa` - it was in the question from the very beginning. Well, ok, the only difference was that I used path relative to my project root - so `ssh-keygen -f etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -t rsa` and `ssh-keygen -f etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key -N '' -t dsa`. Then `COPY etc/ssh/ /etc/ssh/` copies them into the docker image.

Comment: What is the OS, version, and distro of the Docker container?

Comment: @mdpc it's alpine:latest as you can see in my Dockerfile

Comment: Well I googled it, basically it is an enchanced busybox image...interesting.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I was able to find a workaround and indirect reason for the problem - please take a look at my answer - maybe you know something more about it and can provide a decent solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive that it may be in the fact that the default encryption levels are differant.
If you had declaired the bytes in all instances, I think the problem would not have arisen.

Like say:

```
ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -t rsa -b 1024
vs
ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -t rsa -b 2048
vs
ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -t rsa -b 4096
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that for whatever reason keys generated on MacOS host were causing this issue.
But keys generated on a Linux host work as expected - no problem with unexpectedly requested passphrase.

I'm not sure why this happens but it's reproducible. I thought DSA and RSA keys are compatible no matter the operating system.

I'd appreciate if someone could find a more complete explanation but for me the problem is solved - despite the solution being only a workaround without proper understanding of the issue.

Comment: There appears to have been a change to the format used by MacOS Mojave (due to using `OpenSSH_7.9p1`). Adding `-m PEM` to the `ssh-keygen` command fixed it for me. More details: https://superuser.com/a/1404243